# update image from nodejs using multer

Tags: node.js, multer

i have upload image using multer in nodejs and image is stored in database also displayed in website  also but while updating title and description are updated but image is not updated how can i update the image?

this is my controller

```
router.post('/',upload.single('image'),(req,res)=>{
    if(req.body._id == ''){
        insertRecord(req,res)
    }
    else {
        updateRecord(req,res);
    }
    
})

function updateRecord(req,res){
    
    Blog.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.body._id},req.body, { new: true},(err,doc)=>{
        if(!err){res.redirect('blog/list')}
        else{
            if(err.name == 'Validation Error'){
                handleValidationError(err,req.body)
                res.render("blog/addOrEdit",{
                    viewTitle:"insert about file",
                    blog: req.body
                })
            }else{
                console.log("error during record update: " +err)
            }
            
        }
    })

}
function insertRecord(req,res){
    var blog = new Blog()
    blog.title = req.body.title
    blog.description = req.body.description
    blog.img = req.file.filename
    blog.save((err,doc) =>{
        if(!err){
            res.redirect('blog/list')
        }
        else{
            if(err.name == 'Validation Error'){
            handleValidationError(err,req.body)
            res.render("blog/addOrEdit",{
                viewTitle:"insert about file",
                blog: req.body
            })
            }
            else{
            console.log('Error duing record insertion: '+err)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are giving `findOneAndUpdate` function `req.body` as data but it does not include image filename since filename is at `req.file.filename`.

You can give `{...req.body, img:req.file.filename}` to it instead of req.body with spread operator. It takes all properties from req.body and adds img property with value `req.file.filename`. I used "img" property since you set `blog.img` when inserting a blog.

Alternatively, you can create a new object and set img property:

```js
const updateData = Object.assign({},req.body); // Copy req.body in order not to change it
updateData.img = req.file.filename
Blog.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.body._id},updateData...
```